# Facebook sdk 3.18 crash on ios 5

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I added FacebookSDK.framework version 3.18 to my project and made all the necessary updates in the API I call. I get a crash when running in iOS 5.

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_setProperty_atomic
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/947E4E86-E837-4140-876D-06BE9F110296/V.app/V
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

My deployment target for all projects/targets is set to iOS 5. This does not occur in iOS 7.
According to the Facebook site, iOS 5.x is supported.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody else encounters this...
I found the answer to my own question after some more searching Facebook's developer site. Based on the change log, starting from SDK v3.17, iOS 5 is not supported anymore. It now requires iOS >= 6.x. –